# Proving that this set of cantor functions is dense and $G_\delta$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions, baire-category

Let $C$ be a Cantor set on the real line. Define the Cantor-Lebesgue function $F_C$ on this set, and let the collection of sets $\{F_C \}$ be such that every function $F \in \{ F_C \}$ is of the form $F_C +k$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}.$

I can kind of see how the union $\bigcup_C \{F_C \}$ would be dense in the set of all continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ (but if this intuition is wrong please correct me), but I cannot see at all about proving that this is $G_\delta$.

I want to use that this union contains a dense $G_\delta$ set to prove that the typical continuous function does not map a first category set $\subset [0,1]$ to a first category set.

EDIT: By "a cantor set" I mean a compact, perfect set with empty interior.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Cantor set"? Do you have a precise definition?

Comment: @TheoBendit A compact perfect set with empty interior

Comment: I'm also not certain how you would define the Cantor-Lebesgue function on an arbitrary Cantor set. However, as best I can tell, such functions would be increasing, hence I doubt you'd get density of these functions under any sensible norm on the continuous functions on $\Bbb{R}$. Also, you may want to restrict your space from continuous functions on **all** of $\Bbb{R}$, since there aren't sensible norms on this space.